# Magento: Price based on quantity, also based on colors

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.5, opencart

I really need some help from the Magento gurus out there. And even if you're not familiar with Magento and you think I'd benefit from OpenCart or some other solution, please tell me!

I'm building a shop for a dummy print company. I have 4 levels of Business Cards:

1. Standard
2. Premium
3. Superior
4. Luxury

I allow for certain "quantity sets" (though probably not with the actual quantity field):

1. 500
2. 1000
3. 2000
4. 3000

Each "quantity set" has individual pricing... but I also have to account for Colors:

1. 1 Color
2. 2 Colors
3. 3 Colors
4. 4 Colors

So what's the problem? Well, it's easy enough to increment the price if I'm only selecting a "quantity set" (1000) ... but the fact that I also have color options that change depending on the "quantity set" selected, I have two levels of pricing.

Take a look at the Standard pricing structure so you can see what I mean:

[image]

So, the price is DEPENDANT on how many colors AND how many cards.

I have NO IDEA how to organize my products to accommodate this...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the simple configurable products extension: https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/

Make a configurable product based on your three attributes, and simple products for each of your variations. The SCP module will let you set the price for each individual simple product.

Comment: Anders, thanks for your reply. I'm assuming you full get what I'm trying to do... as I've done more research, it seems that I'm not the only one (or million) that get's confused by the configurable product pattern in Magento. Could you perhaps throw up a quick sample for me to try out?

Comment: Anders, the problem I'm running into is that (as you can see in the pricing structure above) the price is DEPENDANT on how many colors AND how many cards. It's not just a matter of +$20 ... I want to cry.

Comment: That's why you need to use SCP. Standard configurable products in Magento let's you add a price for each attribute value, e.g. 2 colors = +$20 which does not satisfy your requirements. With SCP you can set a price for each combination of attribute values, e.g. Standard 500 1 color = $80.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Wonderful. My last question on this... I've created all variations for 1 product. Do I need to do this for every single product? Or can I use the same variations for multiple Configurable Products of the same "type"?

Comment: Hi Anders Rasmussen ,

this extension nothing to work . how it will work i just installed and set custom options in product but it doesn't seems work.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to perform these operation using Store Manager for Magento and reached only first level of your table.

I think you need to create seperate products, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What Anders mentions above works perfectly. HOWEVER, it's a hell of a lot easier when you only have a few variations. In the case of a print shop or a computer builder, you'd literally have hundreds, even thousands of variations. There's just no way in hell anyone would have the much time!